# Toast.makeTest not working in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toast

I've been working with this, from Activity changing to Fragment.

There's no problem until last line

```
Toast.makeText(PagesFragment.this, "message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the .maketext got error.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you show Toast you have to pass Activity reference as first parameter but you are try to gave Fragment reference instead of Activity so try to gave Activity reference using getActivity() method in your Fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first parameter of `makeText` is a context. If you are inside a Fragment you have to use getActivity

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This should work on Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment you must need to give reference of your activity, fragment itself.this will not work. With whatever Activity contaunbs your fragment, it will give you its reference.

```
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```